# log4net - set up XML config to use runtime-specified path for FileAppender

Tags: xml, log4net

We are building a Unity game client that will be run on (at least) Windows, OS X, and iOS. I'm using log4net to handle logging, and I want to log errors to a file using a `FileAppender` to assist with bug reports. I want to place this file in whichever directory `UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath` points to, so that the file will appear somewhere sensible regardless of OS, and I'm struggling to find a way of plugging this into the XML config I'm passing to log4net's `XMLConfigurator`.

I can set a dummy path and change it at runtime, but (aside from being clunky) this has the drawback that by the time I can alter the setup of the `FileAppender`, it's already created an empty logfile at whatever location I put into the XML config, which means I then need to clean up the empty file afterwards.

So, **is there a way to point a `FileAppender` at `UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath` in an XML config file?**

Comment: Once at startup is fine, we're not doing anything particularly fancy with the logging client-side. I just want to point it at a file and let it do its thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can create a custom `PatternConverter` to allow you to do this**

The `XMLConfigurator` resolves `%someString` variables at runtime, so you can set up a custom `PatternConverter` to return the value of `UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath`, and set up the XML so that the configurator will use it to resolve one of your variables.

So, you'll need a class like this:

```
public class PersistentDataStoreConverter : PatternConverter {
    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, object state) {
        writer.Write(UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath);
    }
}
```

You can then use that converter in the XML config like so:

```
<appender name="Logfile" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
        <converter>
            <!-- Tell the configurator that this is the converter for "%persistentDataStore" below -->
            <name value="persistentDataStore" />
            <!-- Tell the converter what to call to do the conversion -->
            <type value="Namespace.PersistentDataStoreConverter, AssemblyName" />
        </converter>
        <conversionPattern value="%persistentDataStore/logfile-%date{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.log" />
    </file>
    <!-- Also specify layout etc... -->
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to set a property which is evaluated during configuration: note that the `file` attribute must be set to type `PatternString` in order to evaluate the variable:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Set_Log_Path_At_Runtime()
{
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["logpath"] =
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "Test.log");

     // Use stream as is convenient for a unit test, in normal usage
     // would probably want to use the overload that takes a fileinfo.
     using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config)))
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(ms);

    var appender = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository()
                .GetAppenders()
                .OfType<RollingFileAppender>()
                .First();

    Console.WriteLine(appender.File);
}

private const string config = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>

        <log4net debug=""false"">

          <appender name=""RollingFileAppender"" type=""log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender"">
        <file type=""log4net.Util.PatternString"" value=""%property{logpath}"" />
        <lockingModel type=""log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"" />
        <layout type=""log4net.Layout.PatternLayout"">
          <conversionPattern value=""%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"" />
        </layout>
          </appender>
          <root>
        <level value=""ALL"" />
        <appender-ref ref=""RollingFileAppender"" />
          </root>
        </log4net>";
```

As this is using [the overload of Configure that takes a Stream](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure_overload_7.html), it would be just as easy to load the XML into a variable, change the file location from placeholder to actual, and pass that as a stream to be configured.

Comment: Why did you ask me above if I wanted to watch the XML file for changes? You're using a stream, but it doesn't look like your solution would struggle if you were loading an XML file from disk and watching for changes. You're just telling log4net what 'logpath' translates to, and it doesn't look like it would need reminding if it detected a change in the XML. Have I missed something?

Comment: No, you're right - I was originally thinking about the second option, replacing the value in the stream, then realised using a property would probably be the better answer, as that then does allow for watching the config file.

Comment: I've been weighing up whether I prefer the solution I came up with or yours. Both are perfectly sensible, but in the end the thing that I like about my solution is that all the work to set up the custom path is handled beforehand as far as the code that passes the XML file to log4net is concerned - the setup code doesn't need to know that, by the way, if you want to use *this* XML file you also need to set up a global property in log4net. But your answer taught me something new about log4net, so thank you for that!